# Display menu items on ActionBar

Tags: android

I want to display my menu items on ActionBar with android
I found some samples but It was not what I wanted

Menu should be similar picture below(Overflow Icon or text)
[image]

My menu.xml is :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapMenu"
    android:title="map menu" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/favMenu"
    android:title="favorite" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/listMenu"
    android:title="List Menu" />  
</item>
```

and my android code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle() + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mapMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.favMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.listMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: which api you are working appcomapt7 or above?

Comment: If you want to display overflow icon, try what i suggested may helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the three dots, irrespective of device menu button, then you can call below code (which is based on reflection) in your application class' onCreate method-

```
 try {
           ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
           Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
           if(menuKeyField != null) {
               menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
               menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

> Caution: This is an awful hack that breaks consistency with the rest
>   of the apps on the platform

Answer (score 2):

Once write following in all item tags

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

then all items will display in **overflow**.

Ex:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/mapMenu"
 android:showAsAction="never"
android:title="map menu" />
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: `android:showAsAction="never"` won't work, use `app:showAsAction="never"` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/main_menu"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:visible="true">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapMenu"
    android:title="map menu"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/favMenu"
    android:title="favorite"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/listMenu"
    android:title="List Menu"
    android:showAsAction="never" />  
</item>
</menu>
```

`android:showAsAction:` When and how this item should appear as an action item in the Action Bar. A menu item can appear as an action item only when the activity includes an ActionBar (introduced in API Level 11).

Try the given code. First you create root item keep its `android:showAsAction:Always` then inside that root item create other items with `android:showAsAction:never`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
but I added android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" and result is :

[image]

I also tested  android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" and menu items hid

Comment: are you want to display menu names or overflow as shown in above picture?

Comment: I want to display overflow

Comment: then once try what i suggested may helps you.

Comment: I tested yout suggested but not show. when I added :      
  try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        with your code its worked. is standard above code?

Comment: dont add anything extra just add android:showAsAction="never" for items in xml that's it, and remaining will be same.

Comment: android:showAsAction="never" display items when menu button pressed, and users maybe do not undrestand the app contains menu.

Comment: no, it will display items when the overflow icon is pressed. if you want to display overflow icon you have to follow it.